# Jupyter Notebook bad HTML export

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have changed the theme in my Jupyter Notebook to `chesterish`:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
jt -t chesterish
```

The Notebook itself is displayed in a nice way, however, when downloading it as an HTML file (`File > Download as > HTML (.html)`), the font colors of the original default white theme are used while keeping the background of the `chesterish` theme, which makes it look ugly and mostly unreadable.

Is it possible to export a Notebook to HTML using the `chesterish` native font colors?

## **Jupyter notebook with chesterish theme:**

[image: Jupyter notebook with chesterish theme]

## **Generated HTML:**

[image: Generated HTML]

## **Used code:**

```
# Notebook

for i in range(5):

    print "Hello world!"
```